# Why can't print a struct field with formatted print?

Tags: rust

Like following code,
it does working to print values with formatted print, when values are primitive values or struct(with derive debug attribute), or something.
But I can't print values when values are struct fields.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

fn main() {
    let a = 3;
    let p = Point { x: 5, y: 10 };

    println!("{}", a); // Working
    println!("{a}"); // Working

    println!("{:?}", p); // Working
    println!("{p:?}"); // Working

    println!("{} {}", p.x, p.y); // Working
    println!("{p.x} {p.y}"); // Not working
}
```

The error message is following.

```
error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'.'`
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
18 |     println!("{p.x} {p.y}"); // Not working
   |               - ^ expected `}` in format string
   |               |
   |               because of this opening brace
   |
   = note: if you intended to print `{`, you can escape it using `{{`

error: could not compile `rust-ex` due to previous error
```

I think that the type of p.x and p.y is i32 so they can printed with formatted print but it doesn't.
Is there any way to print struct fields with formatter print? Or is there anything need to implement?

Comment: The error message is bad, and [there's a Rust issue tracking that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/96999).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is not a formatting problem, just an issue with what exactly `println!` accepts in its formatting string.

Contrary to what you may experience in other languages, the part between braces in the literal string in a `println!` is *not* a string escape, meaning that you could put any (printable) Rust expression. Instead, you should see it as a named parameter. Therefore, it can only be a variable name. `println!` also allows you to mimic variable definition if you don't already have a variable with that name, like this:

```rust
println!("{px}", px = p.x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another similar but different issue is trying to `println!` when you have a Rust variable that is **an underscore**:

```
let _ = 2;
println!("Value of _ is {_}");
```

The error is:

```
invalid format string: invalid argument name `_`
...
println!("Value of _ is {_}");
                         ^ invalid argument name in format string
```

This is probably because the underscore is [meant to be ignored](https://runrust.miraheze.org/wiki/Underscore)

> The underscore (_) is a reserved identifier in Rust and serves different purposes depending on the context. It usually means that something is ignored.

Other sites explain how in rust, the underscore does ["not bind to the variable"](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22449960); or ["does not have ownership of the object"](https://medium.com/codechain/rust-underscore-does-not-bind-fec6a18115a8)

See @jthulhu's comment --not only is `_` meant to be ignored in Rust, the `_` variable **cannot be used** in Rust; therefore isn't even allocated (that explains my error messages). This is different from other programming languages, where the `_` variable is just a **convention** to signify the `_` variable is meant to be ignored but **could** be used. In Rust, as @jthulhu says: "Basically, doing `let _ = 3`; will result in **absolutely nothing even without optimizations**"

I know the OP already found the best accepted answer. I just want to offer this answer in case other folks search for "invalid format string" or "invalid argument name `_`" and find this SO question.

If you tried a workaround like:

```
 println!("Value of _ is {}", _);
```

Then you get a new error, reinforcing the idea that the **underscore variable** is never meant to be used:

```
in expressions, `_` can only be used on the left-hand side of an assignment 
`_` not allowed here
```

So the underscore variable is allowed on the left-hand side of an assignment as in my code above, or this underscore expression where the [`_` signifies a placeholder in a destructuring assignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/underscore-expr.html), **but you can't reference the underscore variable later**, including in `println!`. The only solution is to use a different variable name.

Comment: Note that, contrary to some other languages where `_` is a convention name for a variable not to be used again, in Rust `_` has a special meaning: it *really* means that it's never going to be used again, so it's not necessary to allocate the variable. Basically, doing `let _ = 3;` will result in absolutely nothing even without optimizations.

Comment: Thanks @jthulhu -- you're exactly right, I was accustomed to "conventions in other languages" that `_` was not meant to be used again (but **could** be used again). But in in Rust, you **cannot** use it again! I thought other Rust newcomers might find this point useful, even though your accepted answer is really the best answer....